# kubectl : Unable to connect to the server : dial tcp 192.168.214.136:6443: connect: no route to host

Tags: kubernetes, ip, admin, hostname, vmware-workstation

I recently installed kubernetes on VMware and also configured few pods , while configuring those pods , it automatically used IP of the VMware and configured. I was able to access the application during that time but then recently i rebooted VM and machine which hosts the VM, during this - IP of the VM got changed i guess and now - I am getting below error when using command `kubectl get pod -n <namspaceName>`:

```
userX@ubuntu:~$ kubectl get pod -n NameSpaceX
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 192.168.214.136:6443: connect: no route to host

userX@ubuntu:~$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.1", GitCommit:"b7394102d6ef778017f2ca4046abbaa23b88c290", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-04-08T17:11:31Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.1", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 192.168.214.136:6443: connect: no route to host
```

`kubectl cluster-info` as well as other related commands gives same output.
in VMware workstation settings, we are using network adapter which is sharing host IP address setting. We are not sure if it has any impact.

We also tried to add below entry in /etc/hosts , it is not working.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost \n
192.168.214.136 localhost \n
127.0.1.1       ubuntu
```

I expect to run the pods back again to access the application.Instead of reinstalling all pods which is time consuming - we are looking for quick workaround so that pods will get back to running state.

Answer (score 58):

If you use minikube sometimes all you need is just to restart minikube.

Run:
`minikube start`

Comment: Why does this solve the issue?

Comment: such a silly mistake that i didn't check whether the minkube started or not

Comment: Thanks for your existence. Live Longer.

Answer (score 8):

I encountered the same issue - the problem was that the master node didn't expose port 6443 outside.

Below are the steps I took to fix it.

**1 )** Check IP of api-server.
This can be verified via the `.kube/config` file (under *server* field) or with:
 `kubectl describe pod/kube-apiserver-<master-node-name> -n kube-system`.

**2 )** Run `curl https://<kube-apiserver-IP>:6443` and see if port `6443` is open.

**3 )** If port `6443` you should get something related to the certificate like:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

**4 )** If port `6443` is not open: 
4.A ) SSH into master node. 
4.B ) Run `sudo firewall-cmd --add-port=6443/tcp --permanent` (I'm assuming `firewalld` is installed).

4.C ) Run `sudo firewall-cmd --reload`.

4.D ) Run `sudo firewall-cmd --list-all` and you should see port 6443 is updated:

```
public
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 6443/tcp <---- Here
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

Comment: I did open the port 6443 on master node but it was still not working. ```sudo firewall-cmd --reload``` saved the day in the end. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The common practice is to copy config file to the home directory

```
sudo cp /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf ~/.kube/config && sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

Also, make sure that api-server address is valid.

```
server: https://<master-node-ip>:6443
```

If not, you can manually edit it using any text editor.

Answer (score 2):

You need to export the admin.conf file as kubeconfig before running the kubectl commands. You may put this as your env variable

```
export kubeconfig=<path>/admin.conf
```

after this you should be able to run the kubectl command. I am hoping that your setup of K8S cluster is proper.

Comment: Tried , no luck , i see even admin.conf has same old IP present. Does updating it directly using vi editor works ( replace IP with localhost )  ?

Comment: I am not sure if that will work. You can give it a try!!

Comment: @Vicky you can not use `localhost` as api-server address, because all your generated certificates will be not valid.

Answer (score 2):

To all those who are trying to learn and experiment kubernetes using Ubuntu on Oracle VM:

IP address is assigned to Guest OS/VM based on the network adapter selection. Based on your network adapter selection, you need to configure the settings in Oracle VM network section or your router settings.

See the link for most common Oracle VM network adapter.

https://www.nakivo.com/blog/virtualbox-network-setting-guide/

I was using bridge adapter which put VM and host OS in parallel. So the my router was randomly assigning IP to my VM after every restart and my cluster stopped working and getting the same exact error message posted in the question.

```
> k get pods -A
> Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 192.168.214.136:6443: connect: no route to host
> systemctl status kubelet
> ........
> ........     "Error getting node" err="node \"node\" not found"
```

Cluster started working again after reserving static IP address to my VM in router settings.(if you are using NAT adapter, you should configure it in VM network settings)

When you are reserving IP address to your VM, make sure to assign the same old IP address which was used for configuring kubelet.

Answer (score 1):

if you getting the below error then you also check once the token validity.

```
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 192.168.93.10:6443: connect: no route to host
```

Check your token validity by using the command `kubeadm token list` if your token is expired then you have to reset the cluster using `kubeadm reset` and than initialize again using command `kubeadm init --token-ttl 0`.

Then again check the status of the token using `kubeadm token list`. Note here the TTL value will be `<forever>` and Expire value will be `<never>`.

example:-

```
[root@master1 ~]# kubeadm token list
TOKEN                     TTL         EXPIRES   USAGES                   DESCRIPTION                                                EXTRA GROUPS
nh48tb.d79ysdsaj8bchms9   <forever>   <never>   authentication,signing   The default bootstrap token generated by 'kubeadm init'.   system:bootstrappers:kubeadm:default-node-token
```

Answer (score 0):

Last night I had the exact same error installing Kubernetes using this puppet module: https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/kubernetes

Turns out that it is an incorrect iptables setting in the master that blocks all non-local requests towards the api.

The way I solved it (bruteforce solution) is by

1. completely remove alle installed k8s related software (also all config files, etcd data, docker images, mounted tmpfs filesystems, ...)
2. wipe the iptables completely https://serverfault.com/questions/200635/best-way-to-clear-all-iptables-rules
3. reinstall

This is what solved the problem in my case.

There is probably a much nicer and cleaner way to do this (i.e. simply change the iptables rules to allow access).

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Screenshot

[image: 1]

Select docker-desktop and run again your command, e.g `kubectl apply -f <myimage.yaml>`

Answer (score 0):

Run minikube start command
The reason behind that is your minikube cluster with driver docker  stopped
when you shutdown the system

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).